# How to turn my if statement into a while or for loop?

Tags: python

So the program I'm trying to make is that an user can enter a path WHICH HAS TO BE CORRECT to continue. I thought that I would make a simple prompt to tell the user it is either a valid path or not.

This is my prompt code:

```
if Path.find("Global") == -1:
    continue
else:
    print "Not a valid path."
```

Of course I can't use continue in there but I just don't get how to make this prompt as a loop. The idea was that if the Path contains the word "Global" the program continues with another action and if it doesn't contain the word it will tell the user a message and tell the program to stop (break).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Path = raw_input("Please enter a valid Path")
while Path.find("Global") == -1:
  print "This is not a valid Path."
  Path = raw_input("Please enter a valid Path")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_path():
    Path = raw_input("Please select the correct path: ")
    if Path.find("Global") == -1:
        # "Tell the user a message and tell the program to stop".
        print('{0} is not a correct path.'.format(Path))
        return
    # "the program continues with another action."
    print('{0} is a correct path.'.format(Path))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can break the loop unless your input matches condition, like this:

```
while True:
    if 'Global' in raw_input('Enter a valid path: '):
        continue
    else:
        print 'Not a valid path.'
        break
```

Comment: Because you never captured the variable input by the user.

Comment: But OP never asked for capturing input of user. He just wants to verify if the input is valid or not.

Comment: Alright, I realized I misunderstood OP's idea, gonna change my code.